# Sorting table contents with php?

Tags: php, sorting

I have a table full of band listings for our Musician Finder program. We want to sort them by genre while still only having one .html or .php file containing all the information.

How would I even start to do this? Preferably with php and avoiding JS because most of our users have noscripts.
Here is a link to the test page [HERE](http://www.whatzup.com/Musician_Finder/index2.php). Any suggestions would be great or even just an example of where someone else has done it.

And here is the table [on paste bin.](http://pastebin.com/6qCiXWA5)

Thanks

Also, avoiding SQL is a priority to my boss.

EDIT: So apparently this isn't feasible in php. I'd be willing to use javascript. Or Jquery. If this was just a simple table I'd be fine but obviously mine is more detailed and I don't know where to start and haven't found anything on google. If anyone wants to kindly suggest anything about this that'd be great but honestly nobody comes on here to read about how someone else doesn't like that I asked a question on stackoverflow. Lol.

EDIT AGAIN: Ok so I was looking more... And why can't I just make all my `<tr>`'s 
have `display:block;` per class in css, then use a JS function to change all but the right class to `display:none;`? This would be extremely simple.

Comment: You cant sort data in a flat table like this with PHP. You must use something like jquery or JS to accomplish it. Unless, of course, you put the data into a database or huge array (json or xml) then iterate through them.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Use Google, try some things, if it doesn't work come back and show us what you tried and explain what didn't work.

Comment: He's just asking for suggestions and direction, and perhaps examples of how it's done. I don't see anything wrong with that?

Comment: I have used google. I'm not going to sit here and say "well this didn't work... neither did this, oh and I tried this." That's ridiculous. I asked for suggestions. The suggestion that I just got from @Robert tells me this isn't possible with php. Any ideas on how that would work with JS @Robert?

Comment: Josiah, I'm not a JS expert.. But I did find several hits online for table sorting.. Check out: http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/

Comment: Here's another link for sortable tables http://inventivelabs.com.au/weblog/post/sortable-tables-for-prototype/

Comment: Robert, thanks. Although I guess I worded it wrong, I'd really like to eliminate all the bands that ARENT of a certain genre. So clicking the rock link shows only the rock genre bands. Is this even going to be possible? My boss (Who knows nothing of even html) insists it should be simple but I don't see how.

Comment: Try Isotope. I've got this bookmarked for a project of mine. Sorts. Filters. Arranges. Everything. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: I was thinking maybe something along the lines of including <div>s which are classed with each genre?

Comment: @cpilko REALLY diggin Isotope... There's some great advice, I'll let you all know what I choose.

Comment: I have given an answer for simple string sorting using php only - on condition you put your table data into a php array.

Comment: See my questions edit... I'm pretty sure I'll just go with that. It's incredibly simple.

Comment: I don't see how hiding all the `tr`s is functionally equivalent to sorting a table.

Comment: @Katiek I didn't hide them all. But I did use the wrong wording. I needed to FILTER table contents. Not sort. My bad.

Comment: Oh, well yes - that is totally different.  Seems like your approach will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an existing table plugin in JavaScript would probably be the best solution for you since it would avoid the round trip back to the server to do something that JavaScript can do quite easily. But seeing that you say that JavaScript is not your first option then you can do it in PHP if you choose to store all the data in a PHP array.

So you start by putting all the data into PHP arrays. Then write a function that will sort the array by whichever field you wish. There are many sorting algirithms available for this.

Display the table of data in its default order and add links that will let the user select a different column to sort. In each link you set the name of the column to sort by like this:

```
   <a href="mypage.php?sort=name">Sort By Name</a>
```

You can then simply use the parameter "sort" to decide how to sort your array before you echo it out into an HTML table.

Answer (score 4):

@robert is correct as you can't sort elements on the page without using some javascript. so if you want to sort your table with php, you have to start by putting the contents of your table into data set of some sort, like a large array. from what i understand of what you're looking to do is that every row of your table falls into one of your sortable categories. so then when defining your array, you have to specify what category each row falls under and then sort on that field.

so your array definition could be something like this:

```
$master_array[] = array( 
    'category' => 'acoustic',
    'tr_html' => '<tr><td> .... </td></tr>'
);
```

then sort the array on the category field. a bit of googling will help you with this.

then when it comes to writing the table, just do:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach( $master_array as $key => $val ) {
    echo $val["tr_html"];
}
echo "</table>";
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

If you create a 'Table' object in php, with a `$tbl = array(0 => $arr_row1, 1 => $arr_row2)` etc. property, then you can easily create a view method to render the $tbl in html using a loop.  (All $arr_rowx are associative arrays with the same column names as keys.)

Then you can use this method to order or reverse order $tbl on a string column key:

```
public function order($str_key_name, $bool_reverse = false) {
    $code = "return strnatcmp(\$a['$str_key_name'], \$b['$str_key_name']);";
    usort($this->tbl, create_function('$a,$b', $code));
    if ($bool_reverse) $this->tbl = array_reverse($this->tbl);
    return $this->tbl;
}
```

and to re-index sequentially on an integer column:

```
public function reIndex($str_index_name, $int_start_index = 0) {
    if ($this->tbl) {
        $num = count($this->tbl);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) 
            $this->tbl[$i][$str_index_name] = ($i + $int_start_index);
    }
    return $this->tbl;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jquery. Anyone that doesn't have JS on just won't be able to sort haha. Thanks for the suggestions guys.